# ASP.NET Core Webapi (3.x) Custom ModelBinder Always Returns Empty Object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding

I've been attempting to create a custom model binder and am running into an issue where the object after going through the binder is ALWAYS empty.

I have a good reason for using a custom model binder.  For the purposes of this question, assume I HAVE to use a custom model binder.  In every case where i've used a custom binder provider with either stock or custom modelbinders I've run into this issue, so I've dumbed this down a LOT to demonstrate, but it happens in this specific example as well, and I really need to know why.

I have a simple controller action and DTO class:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<QueryServicesDto>> UpdateQueryService(int id,
        [FromBody] QueryServicesDtoLight dto)
    {
    }

  public class QueryServicesDtoLight
  {

    public long QueryServicesId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public long? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public long? PropagationDate { get; set; }
    public int? CabinetListNumber { get; set; }

    public string GameCode { get; set; }
    
    public string Status { get; set; }

  }
```

Can anyone tell me why when posting valid JSON to this action with no custom binder providert I get a DTO with the proper values, but if I inject the custom modelBinderProvider below I get a newed up model with no values?

```
     public class QueryServiceModelBinderBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        
        

        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context.Metadata.ModelType== typeof(QueryServicesDtoLight))
            {
                var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
                for (var i = 0; i < context.Metadata.Properties.Count; i++)
                {
                    ModelMetadata theProp = context.Metadata.Properties[i];
                    var binder = context.CreateBinder(theProp);
                    propertyBinders.Add(theProp, binder);
            
                }
                var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
                return new ComplexTypeModelBinder(propertyBinders, loggerFactory);
            }
           
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
          
        }
    }
```

Binder provider is added like this::

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews(o=>o.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new QueryServiceModelBinderBinderProvider())).AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

**Sample JSON Data**

```
{"queryServicesId":14,"creationDate":"2021-03-08T17:06:36.053","modifiedDate":16176433093000000,"propagationDate":0,"cabinetListNumber":996,"gameCode":"PGA2006","status":"AC"}
```

Comment: Can you show the json data?

Comment: @mj1313 :  added to the original post